# MongoDB can't start - DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file

Tags: mongodb, terminal

So guys, I've been trying to execute MongoDB on my MacBook Pro (OSX 10.15.4) by running

```
sudo mongod
```

Then

```
mongo
```

but when I run `mongo` command it returns the following error:

```
exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file: 
/data/DB/mongod.lock (Read-only file system). Ensure the user executing mongod is the owner 
of the lock file and has the appropriate permissions. Also make sure that another mongod 
instance is not already running on the /data/db directory, terminating
```

I already added the Mongo folder to my `/etc/paths` and created the /data and /db folders using the command `mkdir.`

There's no lockfile and all the permissions are granted. I also tried to kill the mongo process but I still get the same error.

Any tips?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not owner of mongod.

execute

```
chown $USER mongo
```

Comment: It returns a `chown: mongod: No such file or directory`:(

Comment: try `chown $USER mongo`

Answer (score 0):

On recent versions of OSX you are not allowed to create directories in the root even with `sudo`. I recommend using the `--dbpath` commandline parameter to locate your database directory in a directory you are entitled to write to. e.g.

```
mongod --dbpath ${HOME}/data
```